# How can I center any html content in the center of a browser?

Tags: html, browser, center

I am new to many html code concepts and have a question in regards to centering html content.

In regards to html code, how is the best way to center any content in the center of a webbrowser?

I am specifically needing to do this in a C# webBrowser control, and would like to know if I need to add some styles to my html code, add some attributes, add a specific container or is there another approach.

I am needing to center both horizontally and vertically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a fixed height to your conatiner and add the same height as line-height, then add your content to another container and place it inside the main container.

Try the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.content{
    text-align: center; 
    height:800px;
    line-height: 800px;
}
.inner-content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;      
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="content"><span class="inner-content">test content<br>test content<br>test content<br>test content<br>test content<br>test content<br>test content<br>test content<br>test content<br>test content<br></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center horizontally:

```
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
```

works. To center Vertically:

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: The center vertically code works, but the horizontally does not work however. Did you make a typing error?

Comment: I edited my code so that it now works. I forgot that position:absolute made it so that margin:auto did not work. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    margin: auto; 
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 30%/*whatever width you want*/;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer">
<div class="middle">
<div class="inner">

<h1>The Content</h1>

<p>My Inner Content</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

Css:

```
.first {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.Second {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.third {
    margin: auto; 
    background-color: #cb1c69;
    width: 100%/*whatever width you want*/;
}
.center
{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
.cen
{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/8cvb10p5/1/)